# Collect a merged set of several tables all linking to the same (super) table

Tags: sql, sqlite, left-join

I have come up with an OO-like design of my database tables, with having a "super table" that contains columns that is in all my other tables shared, each of the "sub tables" using a rowid ptr to the super table.

Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE 'SuperTable' (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  created DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE 'SubTable1' (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  super_id INTEGER, -- reference to SuperTable
  additionalData TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE 'SubTable2' (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  super_id INTEGER, -- reference to SuperTable
  moreData BLOB
);
```

For each entry in any "sub table" there is exactly one matching entry in the SuperTable and vice-versa.

Now, I like to make query over all sub tables, giving me a row per entry in the `SuperTable`, with their linked data in the respective sub table.

I've come up with this:

```
SELECT * FROM SuperTable
LEFT OUTER JOIN SubTable1 ON SubTable1.super_id = SuperTable.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN SubTable2 ON SubTable2.super_id = SuperTable.id
WHERE
  SubTable1.super_id IS NOT NULL OR
  SubTable2.super_id IS NOT NULL
```

I saw that without the `WHERE` part, I would get quite a few rows where both sub tables were `NULL` - that's thanks to the `OUTER JOIN` modifier - because `SuperTable` is also used by other sub tables that I did not include in this query.

Here's an example output without the WHERE clause:

```
id          created     id          super_id    additionalData  id          super_id    moreData  
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  --------------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           a                                                                                     
2           b                                                   1           2           more of 1 
3           c                                                                                     
4           d           3           4           additional 3                                      
5           e                                                   2           5           more of 2
```

Rows 1 and 3 above are empty and should be removed from the results, which I currently achieve with the `WHERE` clause.

I wonder if there is a better way to select the rows for the chosen sub tables. E.g. one that doesn't end up first collecting all rows from `SuperTable` and only then sorting out those that did were not in either joined table.

I am using SQLite at the moment, but a more generic answer would be appreciated as well.

BTW, here's the test database I'm using with the above examples: [SO_ 30595895.sqlite](http://files.tempel.org/Various/SO_%2030595895.sqlite)

Comment: Presumably one of the reasons why you have subclass tables is because they store different data - although you could join and show the superclass fields, the problem with the 'uber' hierarchy select (whether `LEFT JOINED or UNIONED`) is that the columns have different names and types? Also, in hierarchies like this, it is common for the subclass tables to share the same PK as their parent, i.e. no need for AUTO_INCREMENT id's in the child tables.

Comment: Actually, I am using the super table in a different way, but I used the OO example because I thought it might look more familiar this way to others. I rather have all these sub tables linked by an "Event" table that records whenever a row gets added to any of my many tables, and so I like to get a list of all "added" Events eventually. I'd dislike duplicating that information in every table.

Comment: Valid point on sharing the PK, but since my use model is actually not that of a OO hierarchy, I end up with multiple such keys towards different "super" tables, making this not work in my case. But I hear you, will remember it for other designs in the future.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to avoid duplicates (caused by the FKs in the subtables not being unique) :
1) use exists:

---

```
SELECT s.*
FROM supertable s
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM subtable1 x
     WHERE x.super_id = s.id)
OR EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM subtable2 x
     WHERE x.super_id = s.id)
-- OR EXISTS ...
```

---

Or, 2) first union the FKs of the subtables, and join the result with the supertable:

---

```
SELECT s.*
FROM supertable s
JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT super_id AS id
      FROM subtable1
     UNION
     SELECT DISTINCT super_id AS id
      FROM subtable2
     -- union ...
     ) x ON x.id = s.id
     ;
```

---

UPDATE. 3) if you also want a (boolean) indicator for existance in any of the subtables, you can use exists() in a scalar subquery:

```
SELECT s.*
  , (EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM subtable1 x
     WHERE x.super_id = s.id)) AS exists_in_1
  , (EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM subtable2 x
     WHERE x.super_id = s.id)) AS exists_in_2
  -- , ...
FROM supertable s
```

Comment: Nice. Though neither let me see the fields of the sub rows. Can that be done? Because when I only get the SuperTable IDs, I still do not know to which SubTable the found rows belong.

Comment: That was intentional. Selectring from the subtables would cause the multiple FKs from the subtables again to repeat (and explode into "partial carthesian products") Unless you add a lot of distincts in the subtable queries ...

Comment: Is there a way to add a custom identifier to the results that depends on which sub table is matched? So that, when I get the results, I can check which sub table matched and then do a lookup into that table specifically?

Comment: If you only need a boolean flag, indicating "exists in subtableX" you could use `EXISTS(...)` as a subquery (exists yields a boolean) Or: use `COUNT(*)` in a subquery, which could only result in 0 or 1, assuming a super_id occurs at only one place)

Answer (score 1):

I should clear that when you have a data set like this:

```
[SuperTable]     [SubTable1]     [SubTable2]
ID               ID | stID       ID | stID
----             ---+-------     ---+-------
1                1  | 1          1  | 2
2                2  | 1          2  | 2
```

result of using multi `LEFT JOIN`s is this:

```
ID  | ID    | sID   | ID    | sID
----+-------+-------+-------+-------
1   | 1     | 1     | NULL  | NULL
1   | 2     | 1     | NULL  | NULL
2   | NULL  | NULL  | 1     | 2
2   | NULL  | NULL  | 2     | 2
```

So I suggest you to use this query:

```
SELECT s.*, SubTable1.*, SubTable2.*
FROM SuperTable s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT MIN(id) id, super_id
     FROM SubTable1
     GROUP BY super_id) s1 
    JOIN SubTable1 ON s1.id = SubTable1.id ON s1.super_id = s.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT MIN(id) id, super_id 
     FROM SubTable2
     GROUP BY super_id) s2 
    JOIN SubTable2 ON s2.id = SubTable2.id ON s2.super_id = s.id
WHERE
    COALESCE(s1.super_id, s2.super_id, -2) <> -2
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems I have not specified the behavior well enough. For each entry in any Sub Table there is exactly one matching entry in the SuperTable. So your solution is probably overkill to my question. The use of COALESCE is a smart idea, though. I might use that also in my original WHERE clause, it seems.